# Swift 5 iOS12 - Push Notifications Not Working

Tags: swift

I send a notification with Firebase, but the notification doesn't come to the phone. I think there's something wrong with the code. Can you examine where the problem is? I'm sending cloud messaging over Firebase but it's not working, no notification is coming. My app is installed in the apple Store. I loaded the certificate correctly.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
            return
        }
        // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Pass device token to auth
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

        // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
        // ...
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    }

    /// Register for push notifications
    func registerForPushNotification(){

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}


extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {


    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print(fcmToken)

    }
}
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        //UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(1800)

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

        self.registerForPushNotification()
}
    func application(_ application : UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
    {
        if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
            return true
        }
        // other URL handling goes here.
        return false

    }
```

Comment: Have you thrown in breakpoints to see what's getting called, what's coming back, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow [this tutorial](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/push-notifications-firebase-swift-5) for sending and receiving push notifications through Firebase Cloud Messaging. The device may need a server key and token to send/receive the notification which this tutorial shows you how to provide. Just be sure not to hardcode the server key directly into your code. You should place into something like a global constants file and fetch it from there.